# F# - how do I index a collection (specifically the PropertyCollection)

Tags: f#, active-directory

I'm trying to wrap my mind around F# so I thought it would be fun to convert some simple C# code that I have that looks a user up in Active Directory using System.DirectoryServices namespace and returns a DirectoryEntry object. The part I'm struggling with is indexing the PropertyCollection that is contained in the DirectoryEntry.

In C# once I have the DirectoryEntry I can get at properties in the PropertyCollection by doing this:

```
entry.Properties["displayName"].Value
```

I'm currently struggling with how to index the collection in F#. Can somebody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a `.` before the brackets.

```
entry.Properties.["displayName"].Value
```

Coming from a C++ / C# background I found the syntax is a bit odd at first but you get used to it.

Comment: ah this one always gets me as well